# How to use "a set of lags (time differences) to retain" in acf() routing in R

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

There is a couple of lines in `R` documentation of [acf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/acf) function.

> **i**  a set of lags (time differences) to retain.

> **j**  a set of series (names or numbers) to retain.

What do they mean and how to use them? I see no relevant example in docs.

(I though that it should be as simple as `acf(time_series, i=c(1,2,4,7))` but it throws warning messages and **doesn't affect the output**.)

example:

```
time_series = rnorm(100)
acf(time_series, i=c(1,2,4,7))

# There were 12 warnings (...)
# In plot.window(...) : "i" is not a graphical parameter
# ...
```

Comment: It is not an error, but a warning

Comment: The issue is with the `plot`.  You can set it to `FALSE` i.e. `out <- acf(time_series, plot = FALSE, i = c(1, 2, 4, 7))`

Comment: @akrun, I see no more warnings but `i` seems has not added anything to out. I would expect it to return just (1,2,4,7) lags. What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't the `i,j` coming from `x[i, j]` and not on the `acf` argument?

Comment: I couldn't find the `i` `j` being used in the source code acf

Comment: @akrun, can you elaborate on this. I do not see what are `x[i, j]` in the context. Besides, `j` looks like a different logical parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 methods suggested for `acf` (`Extract`, `plot` and `print`)

```
methods(class = acf)
#[1] [     plot  print
```

The S3 method for the Extraction (`[`) source code returns and it is a starred one

```
grep("acf", methods("["), value = TRUE)
#[1] "[.acf"

getAnywhere('[.acf')
function (x, i, j) 
{
    if (missing(j)) 
        j <- seq_len(ncol(x$lag))
    ii <- if (missing(i)) 
        seq_len(nrow(x$lag))
    else match(i, x$lag[, 1, 1], nomatch = NA_integer_)
    x$acf <- x$acf[ii, j, j, drop = FALSE]
    x$lag <- x$lag[ii, j, j, drop = FALSE]
    x
}
```

Thus, the `i`, and `j` is based on the Extraction

Comment: thank you. Can you add a simple example where this can be useful?

Comment: @garej I guess the method would become active when it finds a class method for Extraction.  I assume it would be a data.frame, with class having 'acf' as well.  I am not sure about when it becomes active because it is not clear from the documentation